# Максимум соединений на порт

Tags: windows, сеть, unix

Какое максимальное количество соединений  можно открыть на сетевом порту (unix/Windows)?

Comment: http://linuxforum.ru/topic/28352 посмотрите, оно?

Comment: довольно исчерпывающий [ответ по поводу gnu/linux](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2332756/4827341), но теоретическая его часть, по-моему, вполне применима к любой операционной системе.